# AngularJs - how do functions within a service access each other?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory( "TestService", function() {
    return {
        clickString: "click me",   
        clickStringProxy: this.clickString
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope, TestService) {
    $scope.clickString = TestService.clickString;
    $scope.clickStringProxy = TestService.clickStringProxy;
}
```

The above is my failed attempt in trying to make `TestService.clickStringProxy` access `TestService.clickString` (through an elementary 'this').

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eDb2S/96/

How would I go about allowing functions within a service to access each other?

I've tried various atempts to remedy the situation but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the service object manipulate it and return.

```
myApp.factory( "TestService", function() {
    var service=  {
        clickString: "click me"
    }
    service.clickStringProxy = service.clickString;
    return service;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eDb2S/97/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: this won't do if you change `clickString`, the `clickStringProxy` will still point to the old `'click me'`. what you may wan to do is use `Object.defineProperty` and use get/setter method

Comment: @g00fy normally there would be no need to change service properties. If you are using a service as a state holder then I would suggest you use getters and setters

Comment: OP np decided to try to answer one from the tablet, was a challenge making the fiddle :) copy paste still isn't great on the Nexus 10.  @g00fy you have a good point I thought the sample was a bit contrived in the first place though and was just showing that the object could be modified or functions could be accessed by declaring it first before returning it.